# Laravel - how to bind soft deleted route and model

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm using soft delete in model Article, but in model Comment not use soft delete. I'm also customize the key using slug column in model Article. If the article is deleted, I want still show the comment. But when article is deleted, show method always return 404.

```
public function show(Article $article, Comment $comment)
    {
        if ($article->id != $comment->article_id)
            throw new NotFoundHttpException('Record Not Found.');

        return $this->success(['comment => $comment']);
    }
```

How to fix this?

Comment: dump your `$article->id` and `$comment->article_id` check the values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question statement is not defining the problem you should ask how to bind soft deleted route and model.

Laravel provide `->withTrashed()` method for this so it also bind soft deleted models in route.

**web.php**

```
user App/Http/Controller/ArticleController;

Route::get('article/{article}', [ArticleController::class, 'show'])->name('article.show')->withTrashed();
```

**But this method added in** `Laravel 8.55` If you have older version so you can simply find model in controller without route model binding.

**ArticleController.php**

```
public function show($article, App/Comment $comment)
{
    $article = App/Article::withTrashed()->findOrFail($article);

    if ($article->id != $comment->article_id) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException('Record Not Found.');
    }

    return $this->success(['comment => $comment']);
}
```

Or you can also use [Explicit Binding](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/routing#explicit-binding) for specific model in `RouteServiceProvider`.

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    Route::bind('article', function ($id) {
        return App\Article::withTrashed()->find($id) ?? abort(404);
    });
}
```

And you can also use `onlyTrashed()` method in explicit binding in case you use separate route for trashed models.

Comment: If only one model uses soft delete is it still possible to use '->withTrashed()' on the route model binding?

Comment: Yes it is possible it will make no effect on other models.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get deleted records as well, use the method `withTrashed`
Your code should look something like this:

```
Article::withTrashed()->find($id);
```

Hope it help u and happy coding !

Comment: I'm get error when using `Article::withTrashed()->find($slug);`

Comment: If you search with something other than ```id``` use ```Article::withTrashed()->where('slug', $slug)->first();```

Comment: If I want to stick with the route model binding, is there another solution?